# Find the average length of all words in a sentence

Tags: python, string

Given a string consisting of words separated by spaces (one or more).
Find the average length of all words.
Average word length = total number of characters in words (excluding spaces) divided by the number of words.
My attempt:
But input is incorrect, can you help me?

```
sentence = input("sentence: ")
words = sentence.split()
total_number_of_characters = 0
number_of_words = 0

for word in words:
    total_number_of_characters += len(sentence)
    number_of_words += len(words)

average_word_length = total_number_of_characters / number_of_words
print(average_word_length)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're stuck, one nice trick is to use very verbose variable names that match the task description as closely as possible, for example:

```
words = sentence.split()

total_number_of_characters = 0
number_of_words = 0

for word in words:
    total_number_of_characters += WHAT?
    number_of_words += WHAT?

average_word_length = total_number_of_characters / number_of_words
```

Can you do the rest?

Comment: I gave the advice to use longer variable names once when teaching programming, and one student started to use alpha, beta and gamma instead of a, b, c.

Comment: @timgeb: yep, the classics `ADD gin TO vermouth GIVING martini`

Comment: but you can do it to the end, I'm already confused

Comment: @gog  can do it to the end, I'm already confused

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe it should be

```
for char in word:
```

Rather than

```
for char in words:
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `mean()` function to calculate the average.

```
>>> from statistics import mean()
>>> sentence = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
>>> mean(len(word) for word in sentence.split())
3.888888888888889
```

The statistics library was introduced with Python 3.4.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean

Comment: sorry but  I didn't go through this thread

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler way to solve this problem. You can get the amount of words by getting `len(words)` and the number of letters by taking the original sentence and removing all spaces in it (check the `replace()` method).

Now your turn to piece these infos together!

**Edit**: Here's an example:

```py
sentence = input("Sentence: ")

words = len(sentence.split())
chars = len(sentence.replace(" ", ""))

print(chars / words)
```

Comment: can you write it for me please

Comment: I did it but how not to count spaces, see above i edited

Comment: It doesn't count spaces because of the `sentence.replace(" ", "")` statement, which removes all spaces from the sentence.